# sql create function error code 1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to create a function that I found here: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/propercase.txt It converts text to "ProperCase," first letter of every word to uppercase.

```
CREATE FUNCTION PROPERCASE
(
-- The string to be converted to proper case
@input VARCHAR( 8000 )
)
-- This function returns the proper case string of varchar type
RETURNS VARCHAR( 8000 )
AS
BEGIN
IF @input IS NULL 
BEGIN
    -- Just return NULL if input string is NULL
    RETURN NULL
END

-- Character variable declarations
DECLARE @output VARCHAR( 8000 )
-- Integer variable declarations
DECLARE @ctr INT, @len INT, @found_at INT
-- Constant declarations
DECLARE @LOWER_CASE_a INT, @LOWER_CASE_z INT, @Delimiter CHAR(3), @UPPER_CASE_A INT, @UPPER_CASE_Z INT

-- Variable/Constant initializations
SET @ctr = 1
SET @len = LEN(@input)
SET @output = ''
SET @LOWER_CASE_a = 97
SET @LOWER_CASE_z = 122
SET @Delimiter = ' ,-'
SET @UPPER_CASE_A = 65
SET @UPPER_CASE_Z = 90

WHILE @ctr <= @len
BEGIN
    -- This loop will take care of reccuring white spaces
    WHILE CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@input,@ctr,1), @Delimiter) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@input,@ctr,1)
        SET @ctr = @ctr + 1
    END

    IF ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input,@ctr,1)) BETWEEN @LOWER_CASE_a AND @LOWER_CASE_z
    BEGIN
        -- Converting the first character to upper case
        SET @output = @output + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@input,@ctr,1))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@input,@ctr,1)
    END

    SET @ctr = @ctr + 1

    WHILE CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@input,@ctr,1), @Delimiter) = 0 AND (@ctr <= @len)
    BEGIN
        IF ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input,@ctr,1)) BETWEEN @UPPER_CASE_A AND @UPPER_CASE_Z
        BEGIN
            SET @output = @output + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@input,@ctr,1))
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @output = @output + SUBSTRING(@input,@ctr,1)
        END
        SET @ctr = @ctr + 1
    END     
END
RETURN @output
```

END

I need a function to do that, but it's giving me error...

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: "but it's giving me error " is NOT a question.

Comment: I'm using mysql. Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@input VARCHAR( 8000 )
)
-- This function returns the proper case string of va' at line 4

Comment: The code is for SQL Server, not for MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using MySQL, but the syntax you have is for SQL Server. Please read the documentation about MySQL's syntax and convert your procedure to use that syntax. The major constructs are the same, but the syntax is a little different. Here are some things to start with:

- Local variables never start with @.
- `IF` is condition followed by `THEN` followed by any number of lines of code, followed by `END IF`. The `BEGIN...END` construct is not used for `IF` statements in MySQL.
- The functions are different. You won't use `CHARINDEX` but instead `INSTR`.

Here's the relevant MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-routines-syntax.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html.